# How to join a select with itself?

Tags: mysql

1. To join a table with itself is no problem. But I need to join a created select with itself. First idea: to use a temporary table, but I can open it once only. Is this true?
2. Is MySQL smart enough, to calculate a subselect having always the same term only once?
   eg:

   ```
   join (select * from asdf where term) as one
   join (select * from asdf where term) as two
   ...
   join (select * from asdf where term) as ten
   ```

How is it usually solved?

Comment: What does `cerated` mean?

Comment: i think he mean `created`

Comment: @echo_me Makes sense - I thought it was just a term I didn't know (and a quick google didn't help).

Comment: If the inner select isn't dependent on the outer select, I'm pretty sure your DBMS should be smart enough to optimize it. But if you're in doubt, measure it.

Answer (score 2):

You can join temp table with multiple times

```
    select * into #temp from asdf where term
    ...
    join #temp as one
    join #temp as two
    ...
    join #temp as ten
```

Comment: Please, can you show me how? My experience is [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html)!